# Layout files in Magento2

Tags: php, magento2

How do you edit layout files in Magento 2? Overwriting templates files works, but layout files are not working. Can you explain the procedure of editing layout files in Magento 2 in custom theme?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to overwrite the layout file.

Path: `app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

If you want to overwrite `catalog_product_view.xml` of `Magento/Catalog` module (see above path).

Then follow below steps:

1. Goto `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma(your_theme)/Magento_Catalog/layout/` and create `catalog_product_view.xml` file.
2. Here you have to put small code in that file.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
         <!--As per your requirement you can put custom code here-->
   </page>
   ```
3. example: If you want add css then your `catalog_product_view.xml` file will be looks like:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <head>
         <css src="test/test.css"/>
     </head>
   </page>
   ```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I have created a layout file under app/design/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_<Extname>/layout. for the product page. But it shows nothing. When editing the layout file directly, it will be changing. Can you please say, why it was not displaying in frontend.

Comment: I think you have missed **frontend** keyword after **app/design/**

Comment: Try to copy full content from your default xml. and make some changes for just test purpose. so you can analyze that theme level xml file working or not.

Comment: I have copied a default.xml from module_theme to my custom theme and try to add a static block. But nothing is happened.

Comment: give me full path including filename of your layout directory

Comment: Here is a full path of my layout file, Magento root directory/app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Comment: Ohh you mean you want to override this file.
app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml Correct??

Comment: Yes. How to overwrite it.

Comment: But the file I want to overwrite is from the following path. magento_root_directory/vendor/magento/module_theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Comment: Look at this article. This will help you. http://ashutoshpandey.in/creating-a-theme-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

You aren't following the Magento 2 routing system. It has changed completely from Magento 1. I'm attaching a picture so you can see the routing. Follow this link and read so you can have a complete understanding of this new system.

[image]

http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc